# nodejs throws cannot post error

Tags: node.js, rest

I am trying to post the data from html form but it is showing an error "cannot POST".

This is my code:

controller/InquiryDetails.js:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
   InquiryDetails = mongoose.model('InquiryDetails');


   exports.add = function(req, res) {
   InquiryDetails.create(req.body, function (error, details) {
   if (error) return console.log(error); 
   return res.send(details);
  });
  }
```

routes/Inquiry.js

```
 var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.post('/InquiryDetails', function(req,res,err){
 if(err) console.log(err);
 res.json(req.body);
 console.log(req.body);

});
module.exports = router;
```

model/InquiryDetails.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var myskyll = new Schema({
  name: String, 
  email: String,
  state: String,
  country: String,
  school: String,
  profession: String,
  phone: Number 
});

  mongoose.model('InquiryDetails', myskyll);
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var request = require('request');

var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname+"/index.html")).listen(8080);
var mongoUri = 'mongodb://localhost/myskyll'; 
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + mongoUri);
});

var app = express();
console.log("connection successfull");
app.configure(function(req,res){
app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/" ));

 require('./models/InquiryDetails');
 require('./routes/Inquiry');

 app.listen(3000);
 console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

index.html:

```
   <form method="post" id="form1" action="InquiryDetails">
    Your Name:<span class="imp">*</span><br/><input type="text"    
     name="name" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" class="textbox"   
     autofocus required pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+"   
     title="'Firstname' <space> 'Lastname'"/> <br/><br/>

    Email:<span class="imp">*</span><br/><input 
     type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="textbox"  
       required/><br/><br/>

    city:<span class="imp">*</span><br/><input type="text" name="city"  
    placeholder="city" class="textbox" required/><br/><br/>

                    State/Country:<span class="imp">*</span><br/>  
           <input type="text" name="country"  
         placeholder="State/Country" class="textbox" required /><br/>
       <br/>

        School/Institution:<span class="imp">*</span><br/><input  
     type="text" name="school" placeholder="Your School or  
         Institution" c lass="textbox" required /><br/><br/>

        Your Profession:<br/><input type="text" name="profession"  
   placeholder="Profession" class="textbox"><br/><br/>
    Phone:<br/><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phn. no. 
   with country code" class="textbox" pattern="\+[0-9]+" title="Only  
  digits" /><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"   
     class="btn3"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"  class="btn3" />


    </form>
```

I have tried in postman API client to post the data but it shows 404 status while posting the data.
Do I have any problem in my code?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: For starters, the third parameter to the `app.post()` callback is not an `err`, it's the `next()` handler.  Probably not causing your error, but is certainly not correct in your code.  Also, please show the client code or HTML that is doing the post.  Are you sure it's posting to `'/InquiryDetails'`?

Comment: Also, are you purposely using an old version of Express and thus using the connect module?   The current version of Express has connect-like functionality built in and that module is not required.  What version of Express are you using?

Comment: It also appears that you are creating multiple `app` objects.  One in app.js and a different one in `routes/Inquiry.js`.  For this type of application, you will want to be using only one `app` object that you share with anyone who needs it.  That is probably why your `app.post()` handler is not working because it's registered on the wrong `app` object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added my html code. I am using 1.4.28 version and how to use same object in two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple `app` objects.  One in app.js and a different one in `routes/Inquiry.js`.

For this type of application, you will want to be using only one `app` object that you share with anyone who needs it because only one of them is actually registered with your web server and is being used.

That is likely why your `app.post()` handler is not working because it's registered on the wrong `app` object - the one that is not connected to a live server.

---

There are several other things that look incorrect in the code:

1. The third argument to an `app.post()` callback is a `next()` function reference, not the `err` that you have declared and are testing.
2. You are doing `require('./models/InquiryDetails');` and that module exports some things, but you are not assigning the result of the `require` to anything so those exports are unusable.
3. You are initializing the `connect` module, but if you are using a recent version of Express that module is no longer needed as the functionality it used to provide for Express is now built into Express.

Comment: I used app object with this: `var app = requir('./routes/Inquiry.js)`
 I edited my code as you said now its showing configure method is undefined method.

Comment: What version of Express are you using?  `.configure` is no longer a feature of Express 4.  Middleware in Express 4 is installed with `app.use()`.  You are still creating two `app` objects and putting event handlers on the wrong one.

Comment: I am using express 1.4.28 i.e. express 4.

Comment: @gotchha - switch to `app.use()` for middleware.  Use only one shared `app` object for routes.  If you use a router (which is not required in your simple example), then you have to hook it to the one `app` object with `app.use()`.  All of this is described here: http://expressjs.com/api.html.  You have a mix of Express 3 and Express 4 code and are not using modules appropriately.  I'd suggest your first put the code for the server init and one route in one file, run your server with only that code, get everything working, then break it into modules if you want to.